# java.Sql.SQLException, Cannot load class net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver

Tags: jdbc, mule, ucanaccess

I tried to connect my MS Access Database in Mulesoft using `Ucanaccess` driver but it raises error **Could not load class net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver**. I have imported all the required JAR's and added the required dependencies in `pom.xml` also but still it gives same error. I have attached all nescessary details of the problem. Java version - 8, Ucanaccess driver version - 5.0.1 Any suggestion or guidance to proceed further would be helpful for me.

**Error Stack Trace**

> org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: Could not obtain connection from data source
> org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: Could not obtain connection from data source
> Caused by: org.mule.extension.db.api.exception.connection.ConnectionCreationException: Could not obtain connection from data source
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error trying to load driver: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver : Cannot load class 'net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver': [
> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver,
> Cannot load class 'net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver': [
> Class 'net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver' has no package mapping for region 'domain/default/app/tooling-application-85e45b90-5bac-11eb-84c6-ccd9aca566c1'.,
> Cannot load class 'net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver': [
> Class 'net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver' has no package mapping for region '/domain/default'.

**Database Config**

[image: Database Config]

**Pom.xml Dependencies**

[image: Pom dependencies]

**External Jar**

[image: Jar files]

Comment: Please don't use images for text files: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to add the JDBC driver libraries as shared libraries in the pom.xml.

See the documentation at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/mmp-concept#configure-shared-libraries on how to configure.

Example (you might need to add other libraries):

```
<sharedLibraries>
    <sharedLibrary>
      <groupId>net.sf.ucanaccess</groupId>
      <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
    </sharedLibrary>
</sharedLibraries>
```

Comment: Thank you @aled for responding. It resolved that error but its giving another error i.e. Internal server error while doing connectivity testing... HTTP 500 request failed

Comment: That means it worked and you have a different issue related to the driver. I recommend to post a new question with all the details of the new error.

Comment: Problem will still remain the same.. Only Error stack trace will change.. How should I elaborate it as a question? @aled

Comment: Add the complete error log and stack trace to the question.